# Is it possible to pass a fragment in a constructor?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass my Fragment to an ASyncTask class so that I can update a widget or two in the fragment once the task completes. Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    Button loginButton;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginfragment, container, false);
    }

    public OnClickListener loginListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("LoginF", "onclick");
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
            LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask((Polling) getActivity(), progressDialog);
            loginTask.execute();
        }
    };
```

And the LoginTask:

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Polling activity;
private int id = -1;
private JSONParser jsonParser;
private static String loginURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/";
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
TextView loginErrorMsg = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
EditText userName = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
EditText passwordEdit = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.passEditText);

public LoginTask(Polling activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog)
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}
```

So I would like to add a third parameter to the constructor of LoginTask, essentially an instance of my LoginFragment. My goal is to update either a TextView or put up a Toast on the screen to clarify whether login succeeds or fails: as right now, the user has no way of telling how the login proceeded. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As curious says you don't want to be passing Fragments around (they have a 'link' to the activity which is a context and passing contexts is baaad)

You want to pass a small object that can help you call back from your Task to your Fragment.

I would also use an interface. Here's my example:

Fragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnLoginListener{

    Button loginButton;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        loginButton = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            Log.v("LoginF", "onclick");
            progressDialog.show();
            LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask(this);
            loginTask.execute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // Yayy
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailure() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // Boo
    }
}
```

The ASyncTask:

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    private final OnLoginListener listener;

    public interface OnLoginListener{
        public void onLoginSuccess();
        public void onLoginFailure();
    }

    public LoginTask(OnLoginListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            // Something
        } catch (SomeException e){
            listener.onLoginFailure();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listener.onLoginSuccess();
    }

}
```

If you get your head around interfaces your world will open up and your code will look less like the amazon jungle and more like a well organised garden ;-)

Comment: I like this better since it is "closer" to the Android way of things (in particular the Listener pattern). In practice I have used abstract base classes instead of interface since the callback methods often have some default implementations.

Comment: while it may seem nice, you are disguising the fragment and still passing a fragment around.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a Callback interface for this purpose. It is generally not a good idea to pass in UI-specific (actually, context-specific) objects to an AsyncTask.

Here's what I suggest. With this approach, you don't even need to pass in your `Fragment` around.

Disclaimer: I have not actually tried running this code - just typed it off the top of my head. So it may not even compile - it is just intended to be a guide.

```
interface LoginCallback{
    void onLoginSuccess();
    void onLoginFailure();
}


//onCreate code
TextView loginErrorMsg = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);
EditText userName = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
EditText passwordEdit = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.passEditText);


LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask(new LoginCallback(){
    @Override
    protected void onLoginSuccess(){
        //Update UI
    }

        @Override
    protected void onLoginFailure(){
        //Update UI
    }
});

loginTask.execute();



//LoginTask code.
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    LoginCallback callback;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public LoginTask(LoginCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;


        @Override protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params){
           //Do you login logic here.

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
           if(loginSuccess){
                callback.onLoginSuccess();
           } else {
                callback.onLoginFailure();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I have never made an interface before. I won't try to do this tonight (it's 3am!) but when I get started tomorrow, I will look into this solution, and vote up/mark as answered if it works as needed. Thanks!

Comment: I would define the interface inside the ASyncTask and either check it for null, or declare it as final to ensure it is instantiated

Comment: @Blundell Of course. Like I said this code is not 100% - just a directio :). There's whole lot of other things to take care - like show that dialog only if it is not already running etc etc.

Comment: @curioustechizen yeah :) I'm always one for improvement!